# Recursive piping to a function using a list

Tags: elixir

I need to pipe a list of strings through a function to return a string. Currently, I have this:

```
@tag_delimiters [" ", "(", ".", "#"]

def tag(string) do
  tag(string, " ")
    |> tag("(")
    |> tag(".")
    |> tag("#")
end

defp tag(string, delimiter)
  [head | _] = String.split(string, delimiter)
  head
end
```

I want to remove the pipes and use some kind of recursive function to run this based on the `@tag_delimiter` attribute. What is the correct way to do recursive piping?

*Edit for DSL:*

`tag(string)`

When fed `"span(class="foo")#bar Hello my name is Dex"` or `"span Hello my name is Dex"` I want the output to be `"span"`. I do this my recursively looking for characters that succeed the first word in a line. However, I do this by splitting the string using dividers.

This is already working, I am just looking for a more elegant solution to my piping problem.

Comment: Can you post an example of desired input and output? Specifically, it seems strange that you use split to split the string into tokens, and then you just return the head (hence the first token).

Comment: I have added the DSL

Comment: Wouldn't you get the same result by just extracting the first word from the string? Something like `Regex.run(~r{\A\w+}, string) |> hd`

Comment: Just keep in mind this recursive pipeline will not have TCO applied.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian What is TCO?

Comment: `Tail Call Optimization`; because the calling to self is not the last clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Enum.reduce` function to do this.

```
Enum.reduce(@tag_delimiters, string, fn(a, b) -> tag(b, a) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your needs, you can use the [`String.split`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/String.html#split/3) function and tweak the pattern to properly tokenize the input string.

Specifically, you can pass a list of chars to be used as patterns. In fact, you can feed `@tag_dividers` directly. Here's a possible example:

```
defmodule Tags do
  @dividers [" ", "(", ".", "#"]
  def split(string) do
    List.first(String.split(string, @dividers, parts: 2))
  end
end
```

I used `String.split` passing the dividers as a list. I also forced the function to only split the input in two tokens (at maximum): the tag and the rest.

```
string = ~s{span(class="foo")#bar Hello my name is Dex}
String.split(string, [" ", "(", "."], parts: 2)
# => ["span", "class=\"foo\")#bar Hello my name is Dex"]
```

Then I used `List.first` to return the first item in the result. Of course, I could have used a pattern matching `[head|_]` and return `head`, but in case the `split` returns an empty list I will have to deal with the case the result doesn't match the pattern.

In that case, this function will simply return `nil`.

```
Tags.split(~s{span(class="foo")#bar Hello my name is Dex})
# => "span"
```